# Using Bootstrap "Collapse" on radio buttons to show/hide content (NO JS)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I want to create a radio button group that shows/hides content based on the radio button selected. I want to use all HTML and data attributes if possible.

Below is my code:

```
 <div id="parent"> 

     <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" data-parent="#parent" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#div1" />
     <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" data-parent="#parent" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#div2" />

     <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="div1">Content</div>
     <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="div2">Content</div>

   </div>
```

This will show/hode the target DIV just fine, but I need it to close all other DIVs under inside the #Parent DIV.

I know you can do this with panels but I've never seen it done with Radio buttons, and I'm so close.

Any ideas ?

Comment: you mean like this? http://www.bootply.com/q5j7IrpSjT i'm not sure because i don't have a lot of bootstrap expirience. (just improvisation)

Comment: Thats certainly a step closer! The only problem is if I keep clicking one radio button over and over the content changes and the radio button stays the same.

Comment: hmm, i see. I think it's gonna be hard without javascript (if not impossible). Can you show me an example on how this works with panels like you said? once again, i'm a bootstrap noob ;)

Comment: have you considered tabs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do a combination of panels and radio buttons.
Just use the radio buttons as the toggle, and use it to control the panels.

demo
http://www.bootply.com/Fdjc8kQiER#

source code

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                1. What is HTML?
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                2. What is Bootstrap?
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                3. What is CSS?
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the only thing that isn't perfect about this, is that for some reason the radio buttons don't update when you select one. you can't see the selected one anymore. (no idea how this happens... something with bootstrap? pls comment if you know how to fix, so i can edit)

hope it helps

Comment: This worked well given the problem described in my question. I did end up using javascript to solve this at the end of the day for versatility sake. Not sure if there was a better way natively in bootstrap as tabs were too limiting on style. Good solution @Jojo. Thanks.

Comment: Here's an updated version using Bootstrap and HTML (no custom JS), where the buttons are checked when clicked. http://codepen.io/martinkrulltott/pen/waRXgw

Comment: @JoJo The problem is your use of `href` in an input, which causes the input's click event to get interrupted. Use `data-target` instead and it should work fine. bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/U8J7eJh3O6
My solution is the same as @Blizwire's but I'm using the same example you were.

Of course, all of these solutions still have one problem: we still need custom javascript to prevent a second click on a radio-button from hiding the panel it's supposed to show.

Comment: @FireSBurnsmuP I know, the questioner asked for a solution without JS but I've forked your bootply in order to add some JS to prevent hiding elements when clicking again on the same radio button: http://www.bootply.com/PaMuW9v168

Comment: @Blizwire If you re-click an already selected button it toggles the display, and no yes hides the display and no shows it.

Comment: @Martin Your example will toggle regardless of which radio button you click. i.e. clicking on "No" twice will open, then collapse the block.

Comment: This works nicely. One caveat: I found events were propogating from my `<label/>` elements. In this case, the `data-toggle=collapse` handler won't see the event, because the attribute is on the radio button. I moved it to the label and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use the stopPropagation() by jQuery with some adds to your HTML code.

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <input class="radio" id="collapseOne" type="radio" name="group1" value="1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" checked>
    <input class="radio" id="collapseTwo" type="radio" name="group1" value="2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
    <input class="radio" id="collapseThree" type="radio" name="group1" value="3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
    
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    1. What is HTML?
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOnePanel" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
2. What is Bootstrap?
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwoPanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    3. What is CSS?
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThreePanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the JS code.

```js
$('#collapseOne,#collapseTwo,#collapseThree').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (this.id == 'collapseOne') {
        $('#collapseTwoPanel').collapse('hide');
        $('#collapseThreePanel').collapse('hide');
        $('#collapseOnePanel').collapse('show');
    } else if (this.id == 'collapseTwo') {
        $('#collapseOnePanel').collapse('hide');
        $('#collapseThreePanel').collapse('hide');
        $('#collapseTwoPanel').collapse('show');
    } else if (this.id == 'collapseThree') {
        $('#collapseOnePanel').collapse('hide');
        $('#collapseTwoPanel').collapse('hide');
        $('#collapseThreePanel').collapse('show');
    }
})
```

By this way you'll manually control the event of collapse doing it by yourself.
Hope this will help.